# Delete posts based on post meta data

Tags: post-meta

I'm looking for a simple SQL script that will delete posts where the post meta of that post id has some value ['x'].

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_id == wp_post_meta->post_id WHERE meta_value = ['x']

Comment: Does it have to be SQL only?

Comment: I'm not sure what an alternative would be but I just used an INNER JOIN and it did the trick.

Comment: I was gonna suggest deleting from within a script by getting post objects with `WP_Query` and then iterating through them...mostly because handtyped sql is easy (for me at least) to botch. Kudos if you got it though.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE wp_posts
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'InternalOnly' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL);
```